# Why is my cross domain JSON calls not working?

Tags: json, jquery, jsonp, getjson

The remote url `http://remote-server/json-data.php` contains data in this format:

```
[{"id":"1","partname":"R1","date":"10/12/2012"},{"id":"2","partname":"R2","date":"10/10/2012"},{"id":"3","partname":"R3","date":"07/12/2012"},{"id":"4","partname":"R4","date":"14/06/2012"}]
```

This is my jQuery that is supposed to read the above data and display it in the html or php file. This is currently not working:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
var url = "http://remote-server/json-data.php";

var success = function(data){
    data = $.parseJSON(data);
    $.each(data, function(index, element) {
        $('div.outerBox').append('<div>'+element.partname+'/'+element.date+'</div>');
    });
}


$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',   
    url: url,
    dataType: "jsonp",
    crossDomain: true,         
    cache:false,
    success: success,
    error:function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
      alert(errorThrown);
    }
});
});
```

When I refresh the page, I get an error message in the javascript alert box, something like this: `Error: jQuery142452552225_55355545554 was not called`.

I tried putting that remote file into my local server and it seems to work fine with `$.getJSON()` function. Not sure what I am doing wrong here.

Comment: @Mahesh.D then how do I fix this? I changed to `dataType:"json"` but still not working.

Comment: the problem is http:// this is not correct. can not be an external url.

Answer (score 2):

**If the server isn't prepared to handle JSONP requests it won't work.**

JSONP is not strictly a client side manipulation of data, it involves server interaction

When using jsonp the responses should be enclosed in a javascript function.

So to make things simple, lets say for example you have an empty JSON object that the server will return to you. i.e. `{}`

To make a standard request for the object you would do

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',   
    url: url,
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(data) {
      alert("Retrieved : " + JSON.stringify(data);
    },
    error:function(jq, st, error){
      alert(error);
    }
});
```

All that does is make a standard HTTP request and retrieve the empty object from the url.

If you want to use `JSONP` with the same url, you try something like

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',   
    url: url,
    dataType: "jsonp",
    crossDomain: true,
    success: function(data) {
      alert("Retrieved : " + JSON.stringify(data);
    },
    error:function(jq, st, error){
      alert(error);
    }
});
```

What this does is takes the url you have an appends a `?callback={Some Random jQuery function}`.  In your case the random jQuery function was `jQuery142452552225_55355545554`.  The server has to take that empty JSON object and wrap it in the callback, so instead of returning `{}` it should have returned `jQuery142452552225_55355545554({})` with HTTP content-type header of application/json.

Here is a fiddle of a JSON request to coderwall, which fails, and then tries a JSONP request which works successfully.  [JSONP Example](http://jsfiddle.net/2DVSw/)

Comment: Your fiddle is perfect. I tried your fiddle and replaced coderwall url with mine and I am still getting an error. So does that mean there is something wrong with the server where my json script is hosted? If yes what could be the issue with the server?

Comment: Your server needs to wrap the response in the callback, like I stated above if your server just returns the JSON object it won't work.  The server needs to search the URL for a callback parameter and if it exists, it should wrap the object in the callback function.

The server will require some code to implement this.  You can't take the fiddle I made and simply swap the url.

Answer (score 1):

> The remote url `http://remote-server/json-data.php` contains data in
>   this format:
>
> [{"id":"1","partname":"R1","date":"10/12/2012"},{"id":"2","partname":"R2","date":"10/10/2012"},{"id":"3","partname":"R3","date":"07/12/2012"},{"id":"4","partname":"R4","date":"14/06/2012"}]

Well, that's the problem. Your remote url is returning JSON, not JSONP. That's why you cannot consume it. The remote server should return JSONP:

```
callbackFunctionName([
    {
        "id": "1",
        "partname": "R1",
        "date": "10/12/2012"
    },
    {
        "id": "2",
        "partname": "R2",
        "date": "10/10/2012"
    },
    {
        "id": "3",
        "partname": "R3",
        "date": "07/12/2012"
    },
    {
        "id": "4",
        "partname": "R4",
        "date": "14/06/2012"
    }
]);
```

where `callbackFunctionName` should be dynamically specified by passing a parameter to your server. Like this:

```
http://remote-server/json-data.php?callback=callbackFunctionName
```

When you call this url you should return a JSONP response.